# Torch cyclegan model loaded using opencv doesn't output desired image

Tags: python, opencv, torch

I'm trying to load a pre trained torch (.t7) model in OpenCV. The model is a CycleGAN which converts horse images into zebra images. The model can be found here: https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~taesung_park/CycleGAN/models/

I've used both horse2zebra.t7 and horse2zebra_cpu.t7 models but they both return a tiled black and white image instead of a zebra image.

This is a sample input image:

[image]

And this is the output:

[image]

Code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

model = cv2.dnn.readNetFromTorch('./cyclegan_horse2zebra_cpu.t7')

image = cv2.imread('./images/1.jpg')

blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(image, 1, (256, 256))
model.setInput(blob)

out = model.forward()[0,:,:,:]
out = np.reshape(out, (256, 256, 3))

cv2.imshow('image', out)
cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.imwrite('out.png', out)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things missed. First one is that `model.forward()[0,:,:,:]` returns `3x256x256` 3D blob (planar image, with channels at the second dimension). However OpenCV works with interleaved images so you need to permute the dimensions by `np.transpose`: `256x256x3`.

Output values range are also important. For the image from question, I got values from `[-0.832621, 0.891473]`. We need to normalize it to `[0, 255]` of type Uint8. all it one are made by [cv::normalize](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga87eef7ee3970f86906d69a92cbf064bd).

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

model = cv2.dnn.readNetFromTorch('./horse2zebra_cpu.t7')

image = cv2.imread('./images/1.jpg')

blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(image, 1, (256, 256))
model.setInput(blob)

out = model.forward()[0,:,:,:]
out = cv2.normalize(out, dst=None, alpha=0, beta=255, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_8U)

out = np.transpose(out, (1, 2, 0))

cv2.imshow('image', out)
cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.imwrite('out.png', out)
```

Please note that it might be possible that origin framework has different postprocessing procedures. It'd be nice if you could compare outputs from OpenCV and Torch. This is an image I got from script above:

[image]